# Invoke a method with a class instance as its input Arg

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two very simple methods, one of which I can invoke and the other give me not found exception, here are the methods:

```
class SimClass
    {
        public int GeneralMethod1(int a)
        {
            return a;
        }

        public int GeneralMethod2(Input input)
        {
            return input.Numberi;
        }

    }
    class Input
    {
        public int Numberi { get; set; }
    }
```

I simply can invoke "GeneralMethod1":

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Amir\\SimFIle.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType("SimFIle.SimClass");
        object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        object[] Args1 = new object[1]; Args1[0] = -1;
        object result = type.InvokeMember("GeneralMethod1",
              BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                   null,
                   instanceOfMyType,
                   Args1);
```

but have problem in invoking "GeneralMethod2":

```
    Input input = new Input { Numberi = -5};
    object[] Args2 = new object[1]; Args2[0] = input;
    object output = type.InvokeMember("GeneralMethod2",
          BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
               null,
               instanceOfMyType,
               Args2);
```

would you please advise what is my mistake?

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Maybe you don't load the most updated DLL in Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Amir\\SimFIle.dll"). Try using this code: Type type = typeof(SimClass); and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you've got a different `Input` class. You're loading SimFile.dll dynamically, but creating an instance of `Input` statically. That means the `Input` class you're creating isn't the same as the one in the assembly you're invoking the method in.

If you already *have* a reference to `SimFile.dll` in your code, you shouldn't load it explicitly - that's just going to confuse things. If you *don't* have a reference to `SimFile.dll` in your project, then presumably you're creating an instance of a completely different `Input` type.

Either way, you should be able to fix the problem by using the `Input` class within the dynamically-loaded assembly:

```
Type inputType = assembly.GetType("Input")
object input = Activator.CreateInstance(inputType);
inputType.GetProperty("Numberi").SetValue(input, -5);

// Rest of code as before
```

Comment: Type inputType = assembly.GetType("SimFIle.Input");
            object input = Activator.CreateInstance(inputType);
            inputType.GetProperty("Numberi").SetValue(input, -5, null);//Worked, thanks